# Turtlebot Gmapping with RPLIDAR encounters errors

Tags: slam, navigation, turtlebot, rplidar, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i know there were serveral questions about this error, but they are all about the kinect connected to the turtlebot..

I have a RPLIDAR A1 connected to the turtlebot and want to run gmapping slam algorithm. I dont have a kinect connected or any other sensors. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo installed on a Intel NUC build on the turtlebot.
I started this 3 commands in different terminals and a teleop command to start the Lidar scan, gmapping and RVIZ

```
roslaunch turtlebot_le2i rplidar_minimal.launch

roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch

roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
```

It works fine, i can see the map being built in RVIZ but i get this errors in the gmapping terminal:

```
No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.7/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 631 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
```

Has anyone an idea? Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247310/turtlebot-gmapping-with-rplidar-encounters-errors/) by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karishma Thumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/70085/karishma-thumu/) on 2021-02-17**:
Hello Sir,

I am student from Germany working on similar thing. And my problem is exact the same thing. I am using rplidar A2M8. It is working fine with rplidar.launch command indivudally. But I am not able to find a way to integrate it to map with the SLAM. I ran the following commands in 4 separate terminals
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch

roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch

and also
roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch

The rviz window is opening, but the kobuki model is not detecting the map,i.e., the map building is not happening. And although rplidar is running, but is not showing up on the rviz.

Is it problem that i am not using the Kinect sensor? Could you please help me. Thankyou in advance.

Regards,
Karishma Thumu

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-02-17**:
Please don't use an *answer* to ask a *question*. This isn't a forum. You may want to ask your own question and reference this one instead. That should give you more visibility instead of commenting on a 4+ year old question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out on myself:

gmapping_demo.launch includes a 3dsensor.launch file, which starts openni and this does not find any connected kinect (because there is no connected..).

So i just have to remove this lines from `gmapping_demo.launch`

```
  <!-- 3D sensor -->
  <arg name="3d_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"/>  <!-- r200, kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch">
    <arg name="rgb_processing" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_processing" value="false" />
    
    <!-- We must specify an absolute topic name because if not it will be prefixed by "$(arg camera)".
         Probably is a bug in the nodelet manager: https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/issues/7 --> 
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="/scan" />
  </include>
```

---

Originally posted by [schrottulk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28444/schrottulk/) with karma: 63 on 2016-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1